# How to get match path in react new version

Tags: reactjs, react-router, match

What I am trying to achieve is to get the path of the url using match in order to display the shop category.

The issue I am having is that match is undefined even when i did console.log(match), it is still showing undefined.

If I should console.log(match) alone then the page will display the components very well but the match will be undefined from the console but when I include  as it is being used in the tutorial the entire page will go blank and the match will still be undefined.

Please can anyone help me out. I have tried all I can.

Below is the shop.components.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes  } from 'react-router-dom';
import CollectionsOverview from "../../components/collections-overview/collections-overview.components";

const ShopPage = ({ match }) => {
    console.log(match);
    return(
        <div className="shop-page">
            <Route path={`${match.path}`} element={<CollectionsOverview/>} />
        </div>

)};

export default ShopPage;
```

Comment: You can import useLocation hook from the 'react-router-dom' and then use `const location = useLocation;  console.log(location.pathname);`.

Comment: @TirthTrivedi FYI `path` !== `pathname`. The `path` value is the path *pattern* used to match a route.

Answer (score 1):

In `react-router-dom@6` there are no longer any route props (*i.e. `history`, `location`, and `match`*), so `match`, as a prop, is undefined. From what I can tell you are trying to build a nested route similar to how it's done in RRDv5. RRDv6 builds nested routes and links relative to the parent `Routes` component, so it's unnecessary to attempt to "build" the route here, you can simply use `path="/"` for the route and it will be relative from the `Routes` component rendering the route for `ShopPage`.

Example:

```
const ShopPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="shop-page">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<CollectionsOverview />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If `ShopPage` component is rendered on path `"/app/shopping/page"`, then `CollectionsOverview` will be also rendered on `"/app/shopping/page"`.

Answer (score 0):

To get match path in react new version, you should use "**useLocation**" from react

```
import React, { useLocation } from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes  } from 'react-router-dom';
import CollectionsOverview from "../../components/collections-overview/collections-overview.components";

const ShopPage = () => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation()
    console.log(pathname);

    // you can replace all path with "*" e.g path="*" which is commonly used for notfound page
    return(
        <div className="shop-page">
            <Route path={`${match.path}`} element={<CollectionsOverview/>} />
        </div>

)};

export default ShopPage;
```

Comment: FYI `path` !== `pathname`. The `path` value is the path *pattern* used to match a route.